# Realm multiple database problems

Tags: swift, database, realm

There are two databases locally, 'user.realm' and 'person.realm'. 'User' model need to be saved in 'user.realm'. 'Person' model need to saved in 'person.realm' , When the following code is used, the 'User' and 'Person' tables is created in 'user.realm'. I need 'User' model only saved to 'user.realm'.

```
class User:Object { 
    @objc dynamic var id:Int = 0 
    @objc dynamic var name:String = "" 
} 

class Person:Object { 
   @objc dynamic var id:Int = 0 
   objc dynamic var name:String = "" 
} 

//create "user.realm"
var config = Realm.Configuration() 
config.fileURL = dataPath.appendingPathComponent("user.realm")     
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
var realm = try! Realm() 

//create  "person.realm"
var config = Realm.Configuration() 
config.fileURL = dataPath.appendingPathComponent("person.realm")     
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
var realm = try! Realm()
```

When I execute a user database, I only need to create the "User" table in user.realm, instead of "User" and "Person" two tables are created together in "user.realm", I can't remove the Person model, because then you cannot create the "Person" table in "Person.realm". Personally, it seems that Realm is more troublesome to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the key points to know about Realm is that it is not a relational database. While it has that 'feel' which is intentional, there are no tables as such and Realm structures are often split amongst different realms. Check out [Realm vs Other Databases.](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/fundamentals/realms/#realm-vs-other-databases)

In some cases it's more efficient to store like data within the same Realm - a User and a Person look very similar so it may be better to store them within the same Realm - I just don't know the use case here.

To answer the question though, you can specifically tell Realm what object or objects to store within a realm. It's done through the config like this

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(objectTypes: [MyClass.self, MyOtherClass.self])
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

That realm will only have MyClass and MyOtherClass in it. Applying that to your question

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(objectTypes: [UserClass.self])
let myUserRealm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

Will only have one object type in it, a UserClass.

That's covered in the Class Subsets section of the Realm Documentation [Provide a subset of classes to a Realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/open-and-close-a-local-realm/#provide-a-subset-of-classes-to-a-realm)